# Modified double slit with wall(one-way mirror)

Tags: double-slit-experiment

Will this modified double slit experiment produce an interference pattern result? What if the wall is an ideal one way mirror glass whereby it only allows photon to pass through one way but not the other[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcFmx.jpg)

Comment: idea comes from maxwell demon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *one-way mirror* is a physical impossibility.

To see why, imagine such a thing really existed. Then construct two chambers, separated by such a one-way mirror (">" in the diagram).

```
+--------+   +--------+
|   A    |   |    B   |
|        +---+        |
|          >          |
|        +---+        |
|        |   |        |
+--------+   +--------+
```

Photons would pass from chamber A into chamber B but could never return. Then, chamber B would heat up and chamber A would cool to absolute zero. This would violate the Second Law of Thermodynamics (and possibly also the Third).

Comment: Oscar This is to much simplified. The heated up mirror will radiate in the IR range back to the other chamber. A one-way mirror exists only for some designed range of EM radiation.

Comment: @HolgerFiedler There is no such thing as a "one-way mirror". The thing you see in cop shows is simply glass with a high reflectivity (achieved by blooming). It works because the illumination on one side (the interview room) is much greater than the illumination on the other side (the viewing room). On the bright side, the intensity of the reflection drowns out the transmission from the dim side. Aside from that, there is no physical principle that would allow directional discrimination of photons (no light "diodes").